# check if it is a Right angled triangle

Tags: python, math

Given three integers a, b and c as triplets. The task is to check if it is possible to make right angled triangle or not.

*The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case contains three integers a, b and c.*

```
t=int(input())
for i in range(1,t+1):
    a,b,c = input().split() 
    l=[a,b,c]
    l.sort()
    x=int(l[0])
    y=int(l[1])
    z=int(l[2])

    if z**2 == (x**2)+(y**2):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

**Possibly this code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).**
The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
822 1096 1370

Its Correct output is:
Yes

And my Code's output is:
No

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You are `sort`ing before converting to `int`. Sorting `str`-looking digits are done by comparing the digits (i.e. "10" < "2" since the comparison is done using `ord`)

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem you have to sort the inputs before casting them to int. You can use a list comprehension to do that.

```py
t=int(input())
for i in range(1,t+1):
    a,b,c = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    l=[a,b,c]
    l.sort()
    x=l[0]
    y=l[1]
    z=l[2]

    if z**2 == (x**2)+(y**2):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is from std console and it comes as a string. You have casted to int at a later stage but that does help.

Cause when you sorting the list = it just sorts how any string would be sorted.

So input - 3 4 5 is is '3', '4', '5' and answer is True since your sorting by default is the integer sorting.

In the case of - 822 1096 1370, l = ['822', '1096', '1370'] becomes ['1096', '1370', '822'] since strings are sorted in a chronological way.

So your maths op is failing.

```
test_cases = int(input('Enter number of test cases'))
for _ in range(1, test_cases + 1):
    a, b, c = input('Enter the triplets to be checked = ').split(sep=' ')
    pythagorean_triplets = list()
    pythagorean_triplets.append(int(a))
    pythagorean_triplets.append(int(b))
    pythagorean_triplets.append(int(c))
    pythagorean_triplets.sort()
    #     Check if the triplets form a right angled triangle
    if pythagorean_triplets[2] ** 2 == (pythagorean_triplets[1] ** 2) + (pythagorean_triplets[0] ** 2):
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

This works fine for some test cases I testes, maybe for some edge cases you can put more checks or validations.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is from the command line, so it's sorted lexicographically: `'822'` is greater than `'1096'` because `'8'` is greater than `'1'`.

Convert to int before sorting:

```py
    inp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    inp.sort()
    a, b, c = inp
    if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look ma', no `sort`!

```
n_lines = int(input())
for _ in range(n_lines):
    squares = [int(x)**2 for x in input().split()]
    if sum(squares)//2 in squares:
        print('y')
    else:
        print('n')
```